# Clearing temp files - Batch file pattern matching for *.tmp also includes *.tmpll

Tags: windows, batch-file, ms-dos

A file match for *.tmp also returns various *.tmpll files, is there anyway to restrict it to *.tmp files only?

```
dir C:\*.tmp /s
```

Also lists a load of *.tmpll files as well.

Reason for doing this is to provide a simple way of deleting all windows temp files now that CleanMgr has been removed from Server 2012.  Even if restored CleanMgr no-longer works properly, it doesn't have options for deleting temp files only recycle bin and thumbnails.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? What benefit is there?

Comment: As mentioned in original post: CleanMgr no-longer works so server 2012 does not have any way of clearing temp files.  Temp files cannot be left to build up forever without causing problems so looking for a way of clearing temp files, like clearmgr used to do.

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer you could exclude the tpmll files with the following command:

```
dir C:\*.tmp /s | findstr /vi "\.tmpl"
```

You'll probably find other things...